Cannot destructure property 'client' of 'db.config.connection' as it is undefined
Cannot destructure property 'client' of 'db.config.connection' as it is undefined..can anyone show me where i got wrong..thanks...
config/database.ts

import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

// Derive __filename and __dirname
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
import { DatabaseConfig } from '../src/types/strapi'; 

export default ({ env }: { env: (key: string, defaultValue?: any) => any }): DatabaseConfig => {
  // Resolve the filename with environment variable or default value
  const filename = path.join(
    __dirname,
    '..',
    '..',
    env('DATABASE_FILENAME', path.join('.tmp', 'data.db'))
  );

  // Debugging output
  console.log('Resolved Filename Path:', filename); 
  console.log('DATABASE_CLIENT:', env('DATABASE_CLIENT', 'sqlite')); 

  // Database configuration
  const config: DatabaseConfig = {
    connection: {
      client: env('DATABASE_CLIENT', 'sqlite'), 
      connection: {
        filename: filename, 
      },
      useNullAsDefault: true, 

    },
  };

  // Return the configuration object
  return config;
};


src/types/strapi.d.ts
export interface DatabaseConfig {
  connection: {
    client: string;
    connection: {
      filename?: string;
      host?: string;
      port?: number;
      database?: string;
      user?: string;
      password?: string;
    };
    useNullAsDefault?: boolean;
  };
}


tscongfig.json

{
  "extends": "@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "target": "ES2021",           
    "module": "node16",           
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",   
    "esModuleInterop": true,        
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",             
    "outDir": "./build",          
    "skipLibCheck": true,           
    "strict": false,                
    "allowJs": true,               
    "checkJs": false,               
    "resolveJsonModule": true ,
    "types":["node"]      // Allow importing JSON modules
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],       // Include all .ts files in src
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", ".cache", ".tmp"]
}


.env file
DATABASE_CLIENT=sqlite
DATABASE_FILENAME=.tmp/data.db
package.json
{
  "name": "strapi-backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && strapi build",
    "develop": "tsc && strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/koa": "^2.15.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.5.5",
    "strapi-to-typescript": "^2.0.15",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.25.11",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.25.11",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.25.11",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.25.11",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "1165bdd3-f9da-4cad-88bb-00136497d786"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}




//src/api/user/controller/user.ts

import { DatabaseConfig } from '../../../../src/types/strapi';


const dbConfig = strapi.config.get('database.connection') as DatabaseConfig['connection'];

if (dbConfig) {
  console.log(dbConfig.client);
  console.log(dbConfig.connection.filename);
} else {
  console.error('Database configuration is missing or incorrect.');
}



i am developing a strapi application..can anyone show where i got wrong
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'client' of 'db.config.connection' as it is undefined.

Where's the code where you're actually trying to destructure the db object?

From my notes solving this for myself. Here are the things I would double check to make sure that it should work. For context I was working on setting up unit tests.

Double check your environmental variables. At the minimum you need DATABASE_FILENAME=.tmp/data.db in the env.
You're using typescript so in the setupStrapi helper function I stole from here you're going to make a small update.

export async function setupStrapi() {
  let instance: Required<StrapiI>;
  if (!instance) {
-    await Strapi().load();
+    await Strapi({ distDir: "./dist" }).load();
    await waitForServer();

    instance = strapi;
  }

  return instance;
}


Lastly the plugin "strapi-plugin-sitemap" was also causing this error. It needs to be at least version 3.2.1. "strapi-plugin-sitemap": "3.2.1"

